# surprising behavior in scala when using iterator over characters in file

Tags: scala

I'm getting some inconsistent behavior when iterating over the characters of a text file.

The following script

```
import io.Source
val source = Source.fromFile("blah")
val iter = source.buffered
iter.dropWhile(_.isWhitespace)
for( c <- iter ) {
    println("""char="%c", byte=%d, isWhitespace=%b""".format(c, c.toByte, c.isWhitespace))
}
source.close()
```

reads the following file (begins with 3 spaces, then 'a' and a second line of text)

```
   a
bc de
```

outputs the following

```
char=" ", byte=32, isWhitespace=true
char=" ", byte=32, isWhitespace=true
char=" ", byte=32, isWhitespace=true
char="a", byte=97, isWhitespace=false
char="
", byte=10, isWhitespace=true
char="b", byte=98, isWhitespace=false
char="c", byte=99, isWhitespace=false
char=" ", byte=32, isWhitespace=true
char="d", byte=100, isWhitespace=false
char="e", byte=101, isWhitespace=false
char="
", byte=10, isWhitespace=true
```

The `dropWhile(_.isWhitespace)` didn't drop the 3 spaces, and yet `c.isWhitespace` returns true when iterating in the for loop immediately after.

Can someone shed some light on this for me? I've opened the text file in a hex editor, and it looks ok to me (pure ascii, no UTF stuff).

EDIT: using Scala 2.9.2 on Ubuntu

EDIT2: now I'm quite confused. The following is from the REPL on Windows 7:

```
c:\projects\scratch>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val it = Iterator("a", "b", "cde", "f")
it: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val it2 = it.dropWhile(_.length < 2)
it2: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> println(it.next)
cde

scala> println(it2.next)
f
```

Running this exact piece of code as a script instead produces the behavior from the original question (the iterator is not modified by the `dropWhile`).

Comment: by the way, I've tried your code and got expectable results: 'a', '\n', 'b', ... I'm using OSX and scala 2.10.2

Comment: I get the described behavior on Ubuntu with 2.9.2 and Windows with 2.10.2. I'm confused. I've "fixed" my specific issue by introducing a class which wraps an iterator (stored as a `var`). That's ok for now, though I have much to learn in Scala it seems.

Comment: I don't think it is something about knowledge of scala. Seems like it is a bug (just like you I got different results when I tried to execute you last snippet in REPL/as script). I will re-check it and will file a bug if my suspicions are legal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scala, vals are immutable objects. Once a val is set, it cannot be altered. When you call `iter.dropWhile(_.isWhitespace)`, a new object is being created, but isn't stored anywhere. If you want to drop the whitespace, you should assign `iter.dropWhile(_.isWhitespace)` to a new val and call this new val in the for expression.

Comment: I need 15 in reputation to upvote, so I'm ignoring the "avoid comments like +1 or thanks" to say: thanks!

Comment: @AndrewJones, just some clarification: vals are not immutable objects, but rather immutable references. Objects that are referenced by val could be modified, but you could not point to another object.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I get the `val` and immutable thing, and assigning the result of `dropWhile` to a new `val` and iterating on that produces the expected result (the 3 spaces are gone). However the following page contains an example of `dropWhile` which (to me) seems to contradict this: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_43.html

Comment: By "contradict" I mean: I've tried it out in the REPL and the iterator has changed contents after the `dropWhile` call (without me binding the return value).

Comment: But that behavior seems to only be in the REPL.

Comment: @Andrew: answer accepted. I'm still confused by the different behaviors seen, but that's another matter.

Comment: There's a note in the scala docs for dropWhile on Iterator: "Reuse: After calling this method, one should discard the iterator it was called on, and use only the iterator that was returned. Using the old iterator is undefined, subject to change, and may result in changes to the new iterator as well."